# Why calling LAPACK ilaenv in C with the same parameter will sometimes obtain different return?

Tags: c, gcc, hpc, lapack, blas

I used a docker container on M1 MacBook Pro with ubuntu 18.04 and ran a C program. In the main function I call ilaenv to check the block size for LAPACK routine DGETRF with size 1000*1000. The function returned 64 as a reasonable block size. But in the main function I also call another function written by myself and it involves a single ilaenv call with the same parameter, but when I printed it I found out that the function just returned block size = 1, which confuses me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`ILAENV` returns different block sizes for different purposes. The purpose is indicated by passing the name of the calling function to `ILAENV`, which analyzes that string and uses the information to obtain optimal values.

When you write that both calls to `ILAENV` used the same parameters, I suppose that the `NAME` parameter was different in these calls, which resulted in two different outputs.