# ILAENV from Clapack returning different outputs in Debug and Release mode

Tags: c++, lapack

My code has a similar problem as the one detailed here

[Why calling LAPACK ilaenv in C with the same parameter will sometimes obtain different return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138755/why-calling-lapack-ilaenv-in-c-with-the-same-parameter-will-sometimes-obtain-dif)

I have been searching over the internet extensively. The problem is the following: I call ilaenv_ from Clapack and I get a block size of 1 or 64 depending if I am in Release or in Debug mode. The inputs are absolutely the same since they are hard coded into the test I am running. Any idea why this behavior?

```
void test() {
    integer ispec, n1, n2, n3, n4;   
    ispec = 1;   n1 = 1649;   
    n2 = n3 = n4 = -1;   
    char* opts = "L";   char* name = "DSYTRF";
    
    const integer block_size = ilaenv_(&ispec, name, opts, &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4);
    
    const integer expected_block_size = 1;
    
    Assert::IsTrue(block_size == expected_block_size); 
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please note that all literal strings in C++ are *constant* arrays of characters. It's invalid to create non-const pointers to literal strings. You need `const char*` for your pointers.

Comment: What do you mean by invalid? The code has always compiled from what I know. Also ilaenv_ has char* as inputs hence if I change to const as you suggested it does not compile.

Comment: A standard-compliant compiler should not allow that. If you need non-const `char*` then you need to create arrays, like `char opts[] = "L";`

Comment: Well, that changed the output. Apparently it was a silent error that was running since God knows when